# Add multiple columns with the same name but separating them with a [i]

Tags: python, sql, mysql

Here is MySQL code

```
connection.execute(text("ALTER TABLE shotlist
    ADD COLUMN {gear_type} VARCHAR(100)"))
```

Where `gear_type` is equal to `camera[1]`.

What I am trying to do is that if the user wants to add another camera, but there is already one, I will automatically add another column named `camera[2]`

But I keep getting this error

> sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (pymysql.err.ProgrammingError) (1064, "You have an error in your     SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to     use near ''Camera[1]' VARCHAR(100)' at line 1")

Anyone know how to fix this or a good alternative to what I am trying to do

Comment: That's the wrong design... Add another table `Camera` and FK it back to User

Comment: I think M:N Relations in a database are what you need to achieve your goal. Throw away the idea to add extra columns to a table.

Comment: And avoid using odd characters such as `[]` in column names as well

Comment: The error is caused by the use of []

Comment: I already have another table for equipment, but I don't want two separate columns for gear_type and gear_name, the shortlist table I am trying to create needs to store which cameras are used in which shots and give them back to the user in form: column name = camera, value = camera's name "Nikon for example", just so it can be more user friendly. is that possible to do so? or what is the best way to go about this

Comment: A new table is the correct design.

Comment: Whenever you think that your program needs to add a column to a table in a relational database, you have the wrong approach. Period.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is with the `[]` charecters . You might want to avoid using them or try escaping them with backticks (`).
For example:

```
connection.execute(text("ALTER TABLE shotlist
    ADD COLUMN `{gear_type}` VARCHAR(100)"))
```

Or even using this format `Camera#` e.g. Camera0, Camera1, etc . instead of Camera[0], etc .